# Insert an image depending on table content

Tags: javascript, jquery, database

I have a database item (called fairtrade) that has one of the following values: `Yes`, `No`, `N/A.`

These are displayed in the front end in a `<table>`.

```
<table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="25%"></col>
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="last odd">
            <th class="label">Fairtrade</th>
            <td class="data last">N/A</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If the database displays `YES` in the content I would like to display an image. If the database displays `No` or `N/A` I would like to hide that particular table row.

Can I use Javascript / JQuery to make the above happen. I'm not even sure if its possible.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's definitely possible, although we'd need to see the HTML of your table to show you how.

Comment: <table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
        <colgroup><col width="25%">
        <col>
        </colgroup><tbody>

         <tr class="last odd">
                <th class="label">Fairtrade</th>
                <td class="data last">N/A</td>
            </tr>
                </tbody>
    </table>

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to display the code above.

Comment: use `(‘#Rowid’).style.backgroundImage = 'url(tick.gif)';` if you want to display image in a row or use the id of the div in which you want to display image

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will need something like PHP to fetch the data from the database since JavaScript alone is not capable of doing that.
When that has been done you can use the server side language to insert the images depending on what data you get from the database while it's rendering the table.

If the table data is rendered for you you can use JavaScript to show the image depending on a value in a cell.
A simple jQuery example would probably be something like this (sorry, not tested, from the top of my head so might contain errors)

```
$("td").each(function(){
   if($(this).text() == "YES"){
      //code to show image here
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your HTML, the following code should work for you.

```
$('.data-table tr .data').each(function() {
   if ($(this).text() == 'Yes') {
       // show your image
   }
   else {
       $(this).closest('tr').hide();
   }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/VMm3r/)

Comment: Thanks for these very quick responses!!!! Really appreciate the help. I'll implement this now and get back to you.

Comment: Hi All,Sorry for the delayed response. I have added the following to a script.js file but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas??

Comment: <code>$('.data-table tr .data').each(function() {
   if ($(this).text() == 'Strong') {
       $(this).attr('src','http://bradfrostweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/magento-logo1.png');
   }
   else {
       $(this).closest('tr').hide();  
   }
});</code>

Comment: Hi, I have more details about this issue now. You can see the site at:http://www.core-digital.co.uk/magento/index.php/edgcumbes-fairtrade-decaffeinated-filter-cafetiere-grind-227g.html. I have added some Javascript found in the footer of the document but this doesn't seem to be working. Any further help would be appreciated.